# Why does this bind function not work in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master: tkinter.Tk, title: str):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title(title)
        self.master.geometry(f"{int(self.master.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)}x{int(self.master.winfo_screenheight() / 2)}")
        self.master.state("zoomed")
        self.master.focus_set()
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.menu_bar = tkinter.Menu(master)

        self.file_menu = tkinter.Menu(master, tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Hello World!", command=self.hello_world_message)
        self.file_menu.add_separator()
        self.file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", accelerator="Ctrl+Q", command=self.exit)

        self.menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.file_menu)

        self.label = tkinter.Label(self.master, text="Hello World!", font=("Courier", 50))
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.master.bind("<Control-Q>", self.exit) # Why doesn't this work?
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu_bar)

    @staticmethod
    def hello_world_message():
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Hello World!", "Hello World!")

    def exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

root = tkinter.Tk()
MainWindow(root, "Desktop Applications")
root.mainloop()
```

`self.master.bind("<Control-Q>", self.exit)` is not working.

I am pressing Ctrl + Q, but it's not doing anything. The file menu exit command works, but the bind doesn't work.

Why isn't the binding not working?

Comment: Are you pressing control-shift-q to get an uppercase q, or are you pressing control-q? Do you want the user to use the binding with a lowercase q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the letters are case sensitive. For your current binding, you would need Control + Shift + q.

To change it to a lowercase, try `"<Control-q>"`

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

Comment: Thank you so much, and I realized that I didn't put (*args) in my function.

Comment: It should be `"<Control-q>"`. You have the quotes and angle brackets reversed.